# jQuery - .click only activating once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I went through the answers to this problem on here and made changes to my code, but had no further luck. The main issue is, as you can guess, that the code is only running on the first click and doing nothing from there on out.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="Parent">
    <input id="puck0" class="Pick" maxlength="2">
    <input id="puck1" class="Pick" maxlength="2">
</div>

<p id="test"> TEST </p>

<button id="butt">GOGOGOG</button>
```

This creates two input boxes, the text that I want to change to make this work, and the button that triggers everything.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
var choice = [0, 0];

$(function() {
    $("#butt").on("click", function() {

        $(".Pick").each(function(input, value) {
            choice[input] = $(this).val();
        });

        $("#test").replaceWith(choice);
    });
});
```

Following the advice of other posts like this, I changed the `$(document).ready( function() {...` at the start to just `$(function() {...` because the former only triggers once. I also changed the `.click` to `.on( "click"...`, but had no luck there. I even tried moving the array creation to inside the click but still couldn't get it to work. It does work once: the input is put into the array and the p is replaced, but it won't run again and do the same if you change the input.

I must be missing something very obvious, so any help would be fantastic!

Comment: I suppose you know what [`$.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) does. Your `<p>` tag will no longer exists after the first click.

Comment: Yep, I thought it would be something stupid. What would I use to just change the content of an object? innerHTML?

Comment: You should use [`$.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: *"$(document).ready() only triggers once"* yep, but once you have your handlers attached to the tag it should work every time you trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

The event (`click`) works just fine, the problem is with this line:

```
$("#test").replaceWith(choice);
```

It removes (actually replaces...) the `p` element, and from then on, the `p` doesn't exist in future invocations...

I guess what you actually want to do is:

```
$('#test').html(choice.join());
```